# Is it possible to disable IPv6 entirely on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I believe it is not possible using Settings or Apple Configurator 2, but perhaps it is possible using a custom app (which I could put together).

Anyone has clues on how this can be achieved? I know some VPN apps black-hole IPv6 traffic.

Comment: [Disable IPv6](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225155/can-i-turn-off-ipv6-and-just-use-ipv4-on-my-ios-device) for cellular & turn off IPv6 on your WiFi router.

Comment: @zrzka Thanks for sharing. Done for cellular (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nzx9T7GtmT4), but I am looking for a way to disable IPv6 on all Wi-Fi networks.

Comment: @zrzka I called Apple Enterprise Support today and they said it was possible using an app... are you aware of APIs that could disable IPv6 or send IPv6 traffic to a black hole of sorts?

Comment: IIRC [OpenVPN Connect](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/openvpn-connect/id590379981) allows you to proceed with IPv4 only tunnel. But it's a long time I was using it. API? Never made a network extension, but I'd start [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension). I'm not aware of any other way how to disable IPv6 on a system level.

Comment: Btw, I am looking for contributors to solve that problem as an open source project people could self-deploy to their iPhones (who knows who might see this comment).

Comment: If your VPN cannot handle IPv6, it's time to get a different VPN.

Comment: Your chances of getting an app that destroys functionality of the phone onto the App Store are quite exactly zero.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @gnasher729. I am doing research about self-hosting our own VPN and most privacy-conscious hosting providers don’t supply IPv6 addresses. Also, from a privacy perspective, IPv6 isn’t great because each devise is assigned a "static" IPv6 address given how large the address space is... so many privacy researchers suggest disabling IPv6 when possible.

Comment: I am not sure disabling IPv6 for cellular is a good idea not sure on its usage anyway. It depends how your carrier provides its service. As for Wifi again I think it depends on how each network managed. If you want your wireless network to disable IPv6 you should disable it at the first opportunity, that is the AP, VLAN, Layer 2 switch or router. That is not to provide it. "each devise is assigned a "static" IPv6” that depends on a number of factors e.g  is there DHCPv6/DNSv6 etc. If your device is rotating its MAC, a default iOS option, it's harder to make static in the first place is it not?